# What sense to copy empty array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nscopying

I were reading another programmer's code, so i found this:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *assets;
----
   _assets = [@[] mutableCopy];
    __block NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];
```

Is it some kind of trick? Why does he used mutableCopy to immutable array `assets` ? Why doesn't he just create it like:

```
self.assets = [NSArray new];
__block NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [NSMutableArray new];
```

?

Comment: Just because the *property* `assets` is immutable that doesn't necessarily mean the *instance variable* that backs it, `_assets`, is immutable. It's good practice to never make any property have mutable type. It's convenient to back a mutable indexed collection property with an `NSMutableArray*` instance variable but only allow it to be mutated through the [indexed collection mutation accessors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW11).

Answer (score 1):

Just a shorthand to get an empty mutable array.

Instead of `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` it's slightly less code to write -

the `new` construct isn't really used by the majority of Objective-C programmers and was added as a convenience to newcomers from other languages.

Mind that `@[]` will create an (immutable) `NSArray` -
there is no [Objective-C literal](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) for `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: For me, `new` is much more clear than  `[@[] mutableCopy];` What sense to create it and then copy?

Comment: Oh, I see - `@[]` creates an `NSArray`! so in order to get the mutable counterpart you send it the `mutableCopy` message.